# how to make cb slideshow stop after complete 1 loop which have 6 slider images

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, slideshow

I have cb-slideshow by using `html` and `css`

```
<ul class="cb-slideshow">
    <li><span>Image 01</span><div><h3></h3></div></li>
    <li><span>Image 02</span><div><h3></h3></div></li>
    <li><span>Image 03</span><div><h3></h3></div></li>
    <li><span>Image 04</span><div><h3></h3></div></li>
    <li><span>Image 05</span><div><h3></h3></div></li>
    <li><span>Image 06</span><div><h3></h3></div></li>
</ul>
```

But I want stop slides after 1 loop , that mean after complete 1 cycle with all the images.

**the css codes are below**

```
.cb-slideshow,
.cb-slideshow:after {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 484px;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    z-index: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.cb-slideshow:after {
    content: '';
    background: transparent url(images/pattern.png) repeat top left;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.cb-slideshow li span {
    width: 100%;
    height: 484px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 15px;
    left: 0px;
    color: transparent;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: 50% 50%;
    background-repeat: none;
    opacity: 0;
    z-index: 0;
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
    -webkit-animation: imageAnimation 36s linear infinite 0s;
    -moz-animation: imageAnimation 36s linear infinite 0s;
    -o-animation: imageAnimation 36s linear infinite 0s;
    -ms-animation: imageAnimation 36s linear infinite 0s;
    animation: imageAnimation 36s linear infinite 0s;
}
.cb-slideshow li div {
    z-index: 1000;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 30px;
    left: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: right;
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-animation: titleAnimation 36s linear infinite 0s;
    -moz-animation: titleAnimation 36s linear infinite 0s;
    -o-animation: titleAnimation 36s linear infinite 0s;
    -ms-animation: titleAnimation 36s linear infinite 0s;
    animation: titleAnimation 36s linear infinite 0s;
}
.cb-slideshow li div h3 {
    font-family: 'BebasNeueRegular', 'Arial Narrow', Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 160px;
    padding: 0 30px;
    line-height: 120px;
    color: rgba(169,3,41, 0.8);/** OW_Control type:color, key:slidertextColor, section:2. Colors, label: - header slider Text color **/
    padding-bottom: 20px;
    cursor: crosshair;
}
.cb-slideshow li:nth-child(1) span { background-image: url(images/6.jpg);/** OW_Control type:image, key:slideImage6, section: 0. Header Slides, label: Slide 6  **/ }
.cb-slideshow li:nth-child(2) span {
    background-image: url(images/5.jpg);/** OW_Control type:image, key:slideImage5, section: 0. Header Slides, label: Slide 5  **/
    -webkit-animation-delay: 6s;
    -moz-animation-delay: 6s;
    -o-animation-delay: 6s;
    -ms-animation-delay: 6s;
    animation-delay: 6s;
}
.cb-slideshow li:nth-child(3) span {
    background-image: url(images/4.jpg);/** OW_Control type:image, key:slideImage4, section: 0. Header Slides, label: Slide 4  **/
    -webkit-animation-delay: 12s;
    -moz-animation-delay: 12s;
    -o-animation-delay: 12s;
    -ms-animation-delay: 12s;
    animation-delay: 12s;
}
.cb-slideshow li:nth-child(4) span {
    background-image: url(images/3.jpg);/** OW_Control type:image, key:slideImage3, section: 0. Header Slides, label: Slide 3  **/
    -webkit-animation-delay: 18s;
    -moz-animation-delay: 18s;
    -o-animation-delay: 18s;
    -ms-animation-delay: 18s;
    animation-delay: 18s;
}
.cb-slideshow li:nth-child(5) span {
    background-image: url(images/2.jpg);/** OW_Control type:image, key:slideImage2, section: 0. Header Slides, label: Slide 2  **/
    -webkit-animation-delay: 24s;
    -moz-animation-delay: 24s;
    -o-animation-delay: 24s;
    -ms-animation-delay: 24s;
    animation-delay: 24s;
}
.cb-slideshow li:nth-child(6) span {
    background-image: url(images/1.jpg);/** OW_Control type:image, key:slideImage1, section: 0. Header Slides, label: Slide 1  **/
    -webkit-animation-delay: 30s;
    -moz-animation-delay: 30s;
    -o-animation-delay: 30s;
    -ms-animation-delay: 30s;
    animation-delay: 30s;
}
.cb-slideshow li:nth-child(2) div {
    -webkit-animation-delay: 6s;
    -moz-animation-delay: 6s;
    -o-animation-delay: 6s;
    -ms-animation-delay: 6s;
    animation-delay: 6s;
}
.cb-slideshow li:nth-child(3) div {
    -webkit-animation-delay: 12s;
    -moz-animation-delay: 12s;
    -o-animation-delay: 12s;
    -ms-animation-delay: 12s;
    animation-delay: 12s;
}
.cb-slideshow li:nth-child(4) div {
    -webkit-animation-delay: 18s;
    -moz-animation-delay: 18s;
    -o-animation-delay: 18s;
    -ms-animation-delay: 18s;
    animation-delay: 18s;
}
.cb-slideshow li:nth-child(5) div {
    -webkit-animation-delay: 24s;
    -moz-animation-delay: 24s;
    -o-animation-delay: 24s;
    -ms-animation-delay: 24s;
    animation-delay: 24s;
}
.cb-slideshow li:nth-child(6) div {
    -webkit-animation-delay: 30s;
    -moz-animation-delay: 30s;
    -o-animation-delay: 30s;
    -ms-animation-delay: 30s;
    animation-delay: 30s;
}
@-webkit-keyframes imageAnimation { 
    0% {
        opacity: 0;
        -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-in;
    }
    8% {
        opacity: 1;
        -webkit-transform: scale(1.05);
        -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-out;
    }
    17% {
        opacity: 1;
        -webkit-transform: scale(1.1) rotate(3deg);
    }
    25% {
        opacity: 0;
        -webkit-transform: scale(1.1) rotate(3deg);
    }
    100% { opacity: 0 }
}
@-moz-keyframes imageAnimation { 
    0% {
        opacity: 0;
        -moz-animation-timing-function: ease-in;
    }
    8% {
        opacity: 1;
        -moz-transform: scale(1.05);
        -moz-animation-timing-function: ease-out;
    }
    17% {
        opacity: 1;
        -moz-transform: scale(1.1) rotate(3deg);
    }
    25% {
        opacity: 0;
        -moz-transform: scale(1.1) rotate(3deg);
    }
    100% { opacity: 0 }
}
@-o-keyframes imageAnimation { 
    0% {
        opacity: 0;
        -o-animation-timing-function: ease-in;
    }
    8% {
        opacity: 1;
        -o-transform: scale(1.05);
        -o-animation-timing-function: ease-out;
    }
    17% {
        opacity: 1;
        -o-transform: scale(1.1) rotate(3deg);
    }
    25% {
        opacity: 0;
        -o-transform: scale(1.1) rotate(3deg);
    }
    100% { opacity: 0 }
}
@-ms-keyframes imageAnimation { 
    0% {
        opacity: 0;
        -ms-animation-timing-function: ease-in;
    }
    8% {
        opacity: 1;
        -ms-transform: scale(1.05);
        -ms-animation-timing-function: ease-out;
    }
    17% {
        opacity: 1;
        -ms-transform: scale(1.1) rotate(3deg);
    }
    25% {
        opacity: 0;
        -ms-transform: scale(1.1) rotate(3deg);
    }
    100% { opacity: 0 }
}
@keyframes imageAnimation { 
    0% {
        opacity: 0;
        animation-timing-function: ease-in;
    }
    8% {
        opacity: 1;
        transform: scale(1.05);
        animation-timing-function: ease-out;
    }
    17% {
        opacity: 1;
        transform: scale(1.1) rotate(3deg);
    }
    25% {
        opacity: 0;
        transform: scale(1.1) rotate(3deg);
    }
    100% { opacity: 0 }
}
@-webkit-keyframes titleAnimation { 
    0% {
        opacity: 0;
        -webkit-transform: translateX(200px);
    }
    8% {
        opacity: 1;
        -webkit-transform: translateX(0px);
    }
    17% {
        opacity: 1;
        -webkit-transform: translateX(0px);
    }
    19% {
        opacity: 0;
        -webkit-transform: translateX(-400px);
    }
    25% { opacity: 0 }
    100% { opacity: 0 }
}
@-moz-keyframes titleAnimation { 
    0% {
        opacity: 0;
        -moz-transform: translateX(200px);
    }
    8% {
        opacity: 1;
        -moz-transform: translateX(0px);
    }
    17% {
        opacity: 1;
        -moz-transform: translateX(0px);
    }
    19% {
        opacity: 0;
        -moz-transform: translateX(-400px);
    }
    25% { opacity: 0 }
    100% { opacity: 0 }
}
@-o-keyframes titleAnimation { 
    0% {
        opacity: 0;
        -o-transform: translateX(200px);
    }
    8% {
        opacity: 1;
        -o-transform: translateX(0px);
    }
    17% {
        opacity: 1;
        -o-transform: translateX(0px);
    }
    19% {
        opacity: 0;
        -o-transform: translateX(-400px);
    }
    25% { opacity: 0 }
    100% { opacity: 0 }
}
@-ms-keyframes titleAnimation { 
    0% {
        opacity: 0;
        -ms-transform: translateX(200px);
    }
    8% {
        opacity: 1;
        -ms-transform: translateX(0px);
    }
    17% {
        opacity: 1;
        -ms-transform: translateX(0px);
    }
    19% {
        opacity: 0;
        -ms-transform: translateX(-400px);
    }
    25% { opacity: 0 }
    100% { opacity: 0 }
}
@keyframes titleAnimation { 
    0% {
        opacity: 0;
        transform: translateX(200px);
    }
    8% {
        opacity: 1;
        transform: translateX(0px);
    }
    17% {
        opacity: 1;
        transform: translateX(0px);
    }
    19% {
        opacity: 0;
        transform: translateX(-400px);
    }
    25% { opacity: 0 }
    100% { opacity: 0 }
}
/* Show at least something when animations not supported */
.no-cssanimations .cb-slideshow li span{
    opacity: 1;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 1140px) { 
    .cb-slideshow li div h3 { font-size: 100px }
}
@media screen and (max-width: 600px) { 
    .cb-slideshow li div h3 { font-size: 50px }
}
```

Comment: post some code so people can suggest changes accordingly

Comment: please check the updated code with css

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right now in the CSS you are setting the `animation-iteration-count` to `infinite`, so the animation is looping all the time. If you want the animation to stop the slides after one loop only, then set the value of `animation-iteration-count` to 1.

You would just need to change these two rules and that should do it:

```
.cb-slideshow li span {
    width: 100%;
    height: 484px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 15px;
    left: 0px;
    color: transparent;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: 50% 50%;
    background-repeat: none;
    opacity: 0;
    z-index: 0;
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
    -webkit-animation: imageAnimation 36s linear 1 0s;
    -moz-animation: imageAnimation 36s linear 1 0s;
    -o-animation: imageAnimation 36s linear 1 0s;
    -ms-animation: imageAnimation 36s linear 1 0s;
    animation: imageAnimation 36s linear 1 0s;
}

.cb-slideshow li div {
    z-index: 1000;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 30px;
    left: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: right;
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-animation: titleAnimation 36s linear 1 0s;
    -moz-animation: titleAnimation 36s linear 1 0s;
    -o-animation: titleAnimation 36s linear 1 0s;
    -ms-animation: titleAnimation 36s linear 1 0s;
    animation: titleAnimation 36s linear 1 0s;
}
```